# Using button's name that was created by a loop to get data from mysql table

Tags: php

I have a loop that echoes buttons, each with a distinct id attached to them that correlates to a row in a MySQL table. How can I use the name of the button when I use mysqli_query? I wrote the following to base my ideas off of but I was unsure of how exactly I can achieve the wanted result. 
*buttons are inputs with type submit and assume the form tags are in proper place

```
$randomNum = 0;
    while($randomNum < 10){
        echo '<input type="submit"  name="'.$info['id'].'" value="Vote">';
        $randomNum++;
    }

    $b = 0;
    $r = 0;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    while($r==0){
    if(isset($_POST[$b]))
        //get data from mysql table info where id == $b
    $r = 1;
    else 
    $b++;
    echo $b;
    }
    }
```

Comment: So you can't use `$b`?

Comment: @ionutTatu Nope, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @ionutTatu I checked again and the echoed values were hidden under some elements. The $b method worked, thanks!

Comment: Right. I just realised that you echo `$info['id']` in a while loop. I think you should re organised the logic of your app. Why don't you use the `id` in a `hidden` field? And why you loop the id 10 times?

Comment: @ionutTatu I simplified my code so that it uses the same logic but it is easier to read and can be understood by people with similar questions. I am using this for a voting system and have a list of buttons that add a vote to the respective row in the mysql table.

Comment: So what if you have id `12 342 856`. You realise you will loop 12 million times, right?

Comment: @ionutTatu That is a good point that I had not thought off. Is there a way I can do this without looping?

Comment: Yes, multiple ways. I can't suggest one because I don't know how your application looks like. My option would be to send just the specific `id` within a `hidden` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$randomNum = 0;
    while($randomNum < 10){
        echo '<button type="submit"  name="vote" value="'.$info['id'].'">Vote</button>';
        $randomNum++;
    }
```

and $_POST['vote'] will give the id